# Calculate web page size in python

Tags: python

How would I go about calculating the size of a web page (url) using Python. I tried urllib2 and grabbing the content-length header but it wasn't present.

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://www.google.com/'
r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
#Not sure what to do from here
```

Comment: You could use Selenium and Headless Chrome. It's pretty complicated though, but I created a little app for this: https://github.com/jorgeorpinel/site-page-size-scrapper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `urlopen`, you are going requesting the whole contents (an HTTP GET request) so looking for the optional content-length header is not all that useful, once you've gone that way (it's OK, saves you some time and memory, but you have imposed avoidable load on the server and network).  Still, as the existing answer indicates, the `len` of the `read()` of the `urlopen`'s result is the way that will work even if content-length is missing.

Alas, urllib2 does not support the HEAD http method.  To try HEAD, you have to use the lower-level module [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html?highlight=httplib#module-httplib) (make a Connection to the server, call its `request('HEAD', url)` method, call its `getresponse` to get an HttpResponse object, call the `getheader` method on the latter to get the content length header... you see why I say the module is lower-level;-). If you're dealing with very large pages, and sensible servers (ones that do set the content length header), this, while messy, could be an important optimization.

Answer (score 3):

`Content-Length` is optional; use it if it's present, to cut down on bandwidth use, but if the server doesn't send it (or you don't trust it for some reason), you'll have to retrieve the entire resource and calculate its length.

```
print len(r.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. See the code below.

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://www.ueseo.org'
r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print len(r.read())
```