# Is there a better way to retrieve webpage sizes with Python?

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests, urllib

I'd like a sanity check on this Python script. My goal is to input a list of urls and get a byte size, giving me an indicator if the url is good or bad.

```
import urllib2
import shutil

urls = (LIST OF URLS)

def getUrl(urls):
    for url in urls:
        file_name = url.replace('https://','').replace('.','_').replace('/','_')
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print e.code
        except urllib2URLError, e:
            print e.args
        print urls, len(response.read())
        with open(file_name,'wb') as out_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
getUrl(urls)
```

The problem I am having is my output looks like:

(LIST OF URLS) 22511
(LIST OF URLS) 56472
(LIST OF URLS) 8717
...

How would I make only one url appear with the byte size?
Is there a better way to get these results?

Comment: do you mind indent the code ? please

Comment: seconded. I'd have done it, if there wasn't some manual HTML in between.

Comment: I think you meant `print url, ...` rather than `print urls, ...`

Comment: Thank you all. I'm sleep deprived and new to stackoverflow. I was overlooking the 's'!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
print url, len(response.read())
```

Instead of

```
print urls, len(response.read())
```

You are printing the list each time. Just print the current item.

There are some alternate ways to determine a pages size described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909/get-size-of-a-file-before-downloading-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611376/calculate-web-page-size-in-python) there is little point me duplicating that information here.

**Edit**

Perhaps you would consider using `requests` instead of `urllib2`.

You can easily extract only the `content-length` from the HEAD request and avoid a full GET. e.g.

```
import requests

h = requests.head('http://www.google.com')

print h.headers['content-length']
```

HEAD request using `urllib2` or `httplib2` detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421170/python-head-request-with-urllib2).

Comment: Thank you for the links. I'm reading up on requests and it does look like it would fit my needs better. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

> How would I make only one url appear with the byte size?

Obviously: don't

```
print urls, ...
```

but

```
print url, ...
```